# Spring Data Redis - Support for command PUBSUB CHANNELS

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

The RedisTemplate does not support the **PUBSUB CHANNELS** command. So one way would be to do the following

```
   private JedisPool getJedisPool(){
        if (jedisPool == null)
        jedisPool = new JedisPool(redisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig(), redisConnectionFactory.getHostName(), redisConnectionFactory.getPort());
        return jedisPool;
    }

    public Integer getNumChannels() {
        Integer count = 0;
        try (Jedis jedis = getJedisPool().getResource()) {
            List<String> channels = jedis.pubsubChannels("user.*");
            count = channels == null ? 0 : channels.size();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("unable to get user count", e);
        } finally {
            //getJedisPool().close(); //No need for close or returnResource()
        }
    }
```

Is this the suggested approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you're heading to.
If you plan to use it only for your own application, then you can obtain a `JedisConnection` from `JedisConnectionFactory` and use the underlying `Jedis` instance to invoke commands.

```
JedisConnectionFactory factory = …

// assuming you're using Redis Standalone or Redis Sentinel
RedisConnection connection = factory.getConnection();
try {
    if (connection instanceof JedisConnection) {
        Jedis jedis = ((JedisConnection) connection).getNativeConnection();
        List<String> strings = jedis.pubsubChannels("…");
    }
} finally {
    connection.close();
}
```

Please note this works only with Redis Standalone/Redis Sentinel but not with Redis Cluster as `JedisCluster` does not expose `pubsubChannels`.